# Accessibility - make dropdown (sub) menu keyboard accessible as well

Tags: css, accessibility, navbar, dropdown

I am trying to make the dropdown menu of my navigation bar keyboard accessible as well. However, unsuccessfully. I have read WAI instructions and applied them but it doesn't seem to work. I don't want to use javascript (if possible)! The following is the code:

```
<nav id="main-menu" role="navigation" aria-label="Main navigation" role="navigation"class="fixed">
    <ul class="sf-menu fixed" id="menu">
         <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Υπουργείο</a>
              <ul role="menubar" aria-label="Main Menu" >
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Όραμα και Αποστολή</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Υπουργός</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Γενικός Διευθυντής</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Προηγούμενοι Υπουργοί</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Οργανωτική Δομή</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#" role="menuitem">Συμβούλια / Επιτροπές</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#">Επιδόματα και Παροχές</a>
                <ul>
                            <li><a href="#">Ελάχιστο Εγγυημένο Εισόδημα και Δημόσιο Βοήθημα</a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown"><a href="#">Οικογένειας και Παιδιού</a>
                                <ul>
                                    <li><a href="#">Ειδικό Βοήθημα Τοκετού σε Άγαμες Μητέρες</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Επίδομα Τέκνου, Επίδομα Μονογονεϊκής Οικογένειας</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Τιμητικό Επίδομα Πολύτεκνης Μάνας</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Επίδομα Πατρότητας</a>
                                    <li><a href="#">Σχέδιο Παραχώρησης Ωφελημάτων σε Οικογένειες που Αποκτούν Τρίδυμα και Άνω</a>       </ul>
                          </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Εργασίας/Ανεργίας</a></li>
                </ul>
          </li>
    </ul>
```

Also, I would like to add a small arrow which changes accordingly when the menu is expanded/collapsed. How can I do that with CSS and for it to be keyboard accessible as well?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Two things, 1. can you create a fiddle that includes your CSS so that we can see where you are up to and what the problem is (as you haven't actually explained why it isn't accessible). 2. You will have to use JavaScript in order to facilitate the use of `aria-expanded` as a bear minimum so there isn't much you can do there I am afraid. If you can get a fiddle together and explain a little bit further what the issues are that you are experiencing we can help no problem!

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. The fiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/fatsoua/5phL6efv/.

Comment: 1. I would like to avoid the use of javascript, is there another way of making the dropdown menu keyboard navigable and accessible as well, without the use of aria-expanded?
2. As it is now, with the keyboard (tab) you cannot open/navigate the dropdown menu. what am I missing?
3. I have arrows to indicate that there is a dropdown but they are not being displayed. I want the direction to change accordingly, expanded/collapsed.
Thank you.